# windows defenderを自動的にフルスキャンをしたい

Tags: windows-10

windows defenderを入れています。
windows10です。
定期的にフルスキャンをしたいと思っています。
タスクスケジューラで1週間に1回で、定期実行しようと設定をしましたがうまくいきません。
何か良い方法で定期実行できますか？
宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

[Windows セキュリティを使ってデバイスを保護する](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/help/17464/windows-10-help-protect-my-device-with-windows-security)で説明されていますが、

Windows Defenderでは、タスクスケジューラーにスキャンタスクが登録済みですので、希望のタイミングで実行されるようトリガーを設定するだけとなっています。

---

「うまくいきません」とのことですが、この方法で実現できないのであれば、何がどううまく行かないのかを説明してください。

Comment: 私がやったこととして、タスクスケジューラ→Microsoft→Windows→Windowsdefenderの中のWindows Defender Scheduled Scanからトリガーで作成して、3分後に実行しようとしたが状態が準備完了のままトリガーが動きません。全般のユーザーがログオンしているかどうかにかかわらず実行するに変えたり微調整しましたが、動きませんでした。

Answer (score 1):

具体的な手順や指定内容は判りませんが、以下のページが参考になると思います。

一番適合しそうなページは以下になります。
[スケジュールされたクイック スキャンまたはフル Windows Defender ウイルス対策スキャンを構成します。](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-antivirus/scheduled-catch-up-scans-windows-defender-antivirus)

他には簡単な説明のページがいくつかあります。
[コマンドライン(CUI)で Windows Defender](http://cpthgli.hatenablog.jp/entry/2017/02/15/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%28CUI%29%E3%81%A7_Windows_Defender)
こちらはWindows7ですが[ヒント: コマンド ラインで Windows Defender を実行 (自動化) する](https://technet.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/win7_tips54.aspx)
そして自動翻訳で文章がおかしいですが、Windows10の資料
[構成し、mpcmdrun.exe コマンド ライン ツールを使った Windows Defender ウイルス対策の管理](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-antivirus/command-line-arguments-windows-defender-antivirus)

Windows10関連の先頭ページは以下になるので、これ以後の資料を調べてみてください。
[Windows Defender Advanced Threat Protection](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-atp/windows-defender-advanced-threat-protection)